# how to create one scrollbar for 3 recyclerView android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I need to create 1 scrollbar to scroll 3x recyclerView at the same time, i know that it is possible to scroll RView with layoutMatager.scrollTo etc but i dont understand how to make scrollbar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things , you need to do.

1. Wrap up recyclerviews inside nested scrollview.

   ```
   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

     //<RecyclerView 1>
     //<RecyclerView 2>
     //<RecyclerView 3>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
   ```
2. And then call [setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean)) function to the recyclerview like this while setting adapter.

> ```
>  recycler1.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false 
>  recycler2.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false 
>  recycler3.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
> ```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work for me, I probably described the problem badly, I need rv 1,2,3 to scroll individually and nestedScrollView to scroll them all.